# Errors installing Material Design for android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, material-design

I've been getting familiar with Android Studio for the last couple of days and it has been stable for the most part , until I added the Material Design dependency and I got a whole bunch of errors when building the project.

I've been tinkering around with buildtools/sdk versions but nothing seems to work.

Here's my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.anuythe.com.apend"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Errors:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYWDg.png

Comment: Use compileSdkVersion 29 and don't mix androidx libraries with support libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you upgrade to AndroidX:

```
 dependencies {

  implementation 
'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat.appcompat:1.1.0'
 implementation 
 'androidx.constraintlayout.constraintlayout:1.1.3'
 }
```

PS: the versions are not the latest though, just pointing u in the right direction.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you , it seems I missed the bit in the documentation about the androidx part
Much appreciation